# Optimize calls to a commonly called, expensive query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a view in my database which returns the last updated value for a number of tables. This is to prevent those tables being queried directly for changes by the application, the application is in a multi user environment and these tables may be frequently updated for short bursts, then ignored for hours at a time.

I have a view called `vwLastUpated`

```
CREATE VIEW vwLastUpdated as
SELECT Tasks, Items, ListItems FROM
    (Select Max(ModifiedTime) as Tasks from tblTasks) a CROSS JOIN
    (Select Max(ModifiedTime) as Items from tblItems) b CROSS JOIN
    (Select Max(ModifiedTime) as ListItems from tblListItem) c
```

Clients are configured to call this view around every 10-30 seconds (user configurable), the trouble is, when there are a lot of clients (around 80 at one site), the view gets hit very, very frequently, and can sometimes take a few milliseconds to run, but sometimes takes 200-300 ms to run if updates are occurring, this seems to be slowing down the front end during heavy use. The tables are properly indexed on `ModifiedTime DESC`.

These sites are using SQL Express in some cases, at other sites they have the full version of SQL and I can design the view differently and use Agent to update a common table (`tblLastUpdated`) where Agent updates the table directly by essentially running the above query every 5 seconds.

What could I do to make the process more efficient and reduce the load on the database server where SQL Express is used?

The client sites are on a minimum of SQL Server 2008 (up to SQL 2012)

Comment: Adding `with (nolock)` should be okay in this situation because the data you've just read can become invalid a millisecond later anyway.

Comment: You can create table with all the info and recreate it every 10 seconds. Then clients can query only tiny table with 1 row and 3 columns. Or maybe better you can write a trigger that will update this small table everytime somehing is added/changed/deleted.

Comment: Is there a way to create a small table every 10 seconds in SQL Express (ie with no SQL Server agent)? This is exactly what I do when I have Agent to leverage, but apart from writing my own service I can't see how to do it. I am thinking about a Stored Procedure that each client calls, which reads a timestamp and if more than 10 seconds populates a table, otherwise returns the table, each time it is called? In the meantime I am going to try the nolock hint.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on the following fields?

```
tblTasks(ModifiedTime)
tblItems(ModifiedTime)
ListItems(ModifiedTime)
```

This should ensure pretty good performance.

If you do, and there is still the problem of interacting locks, then you might consider having another table with this information.  If you do updates/inserts directly on the tables, this would require triggers.  If you wrap updates and inserts in stored procedures, then you can do the changes there.

This would basically be turning the view into a table and updating that table whenever the data changes.  That update should be very fast and have minimal interaction with other queries.

Comment: Yes, he does: *The tables are properly indexed on `ModifiedTime DESC`.*

Comment: I doubt another table would solve it. The data would have to get to that another table in the first place, and the issue with the current setup is locking time, where `max()` has to wait for x-locks to be released. The same waiting issue would apply to the trigger.

Comment: @GSerg . . . Another table with three rows (one for each table) would have minimal impact on locking.  Remember, when the current table is being updated, things like indexes also have to be updated.  That wouldn't be the case with a small summary table.  But, if `nolock` fixes the problem, that is even better.

Comment: The trigger writes to the little table - the row in the little table gets x-locked - the client waits for the x-lock to be released so that it can read the value - in the meantime there are 85 other trigger instances waiting for the same x-lock to update the same row in the little table with their, more recent, values - same waiting issue experienced by the client when the client loses to several triggers in a row on waiting for the x-lock. That could probably be solved by `nolock` too, but if so, then `nolock` would solve the original problem directly.

Comment: Yep, I originally had this as a trigger and it was a disaster. :(

Comment: @Molloch . . . First, how are you updating the modified date without a trigger?  Second, what were you doing inside the trigger?  I was suggesting a very short trigger that simply updates a value in a very small table.